# Inner join using two fields: use one or two indexes?

Tags: sql-server

I have this escenario:

```
TableA: +2M rows.
TableB: +60K rows.
```

I need to `INNER JOIN` them by two fields `([Month] AS INT, [Year] AS INT)`.

I'm looking to improve the performance of that query; for that I could create an Index for `[Month, Year]` or I could create two sepparate indexes for `[Month]` and `[Year]`. What criteria should I consider to choose one of these two approaches?

Comment: Partitioning is always an option. A composite index on `[Month, Year]` would be sufficient as long as your query uses both columns in that order.

Comment: Interesting question. Some links to throw some light: [link1](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/tuning-joins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you ever search for `year` without also searching for `month`? What about searching for `month` without ever searching for `year`?

If you will never search for one of these columns without also searching for the other, then create an index including both columns.

If you will only ever search for `month`, or `month` and `year`, then create an index for `month`, `year`, noting that `month` is the leading edge of the index.

If you will search for each column individually at times, create two separate indexes, one for each column... Sql Server can effectively use both these indexes if searching for both columns at the same time.

Comment: I do need to perfom operations (selects, updates and deletes) filtering only by year or only by month. Thanks for your answer!